# EditorForModel does not render ICollection property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using the `EditorForModel` helper on a class that have a property of type `ICollection<int>` unfortunatlly I can not see my control render in my page.

Here is the sample:

The model view object

```
public class CopyFromVM
{

    [UIHint("MultiEntityList")]
    public ICollection<int> EntityIds { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In the EditorTemplate folder I have the file MultiEntityList.cshtml

```
@model ICollection<int>


<select name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" multiple="multiple" >
 ...
</select>
```

When the form is render I don't have any error of any kind. The properties is just ignore from the rendering.  So I am suspecting that `EditorForModel` is ignoring complex type. Looking at the web it should work properly for all type.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should pick up the custom template from your main view:

```
@model CopyFromVM
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.EntityIds)
```

The following will not:

```
@model CopyFromVM
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

The reason for that is because the framework doesn't recurse into complex object properties. You could modify the `Object.cshtml` default editor template as explained by Brad Wilson in [this blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) (look at the *Shallow Dive vs. Deep Dive* section towards the end of his post).

Also make sure that your editor template is placed into the correct folder: `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MultiEntityList.cshtml` and not `EditorTemplate` as stated in your question (notice the missing `s`).

---

As a side remark, the way you are generating the name and id attributes of your select list inside the editor template is not correct because you are not taking into account the nesting level. Imagine for example that `CopyFromVM` is used as a property of yet another parent view model. In this case the name of the select will be wrong and the default model binder won't be able to rehydrate the value: Use the following instead:

```
@model ICollection<int>
<select name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")" multiple="multiple" >
    ...
</select>
```

Well, actually, no, you already have helpers that do this job for you `@Html.ListBox`. Hardcoding HTML form elements in ASP.NET MVC views seems a pretty fragile process that I would recommend you to avoid.

---

And yet another side remark: in order to generate a select list you normally need 2 properties on your view model: one that will hold the selected values and one that will hold all the values. So strongly typing your editor template to `ICollection<int>` is IMHO a wrong approach here.

Comment: :( IMO it does not make sense to not recurs. Especially that I have add the UIHint attribute. I rather have an attribute that stop recursing like ScaffoldColumn for example and by default it should recurse. Bloody bodgy framework. Anyway thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: The 's' is a typo in  my question sorry for that.

Comment: @mathk, it's absolutely trivial to write a custom editor template for `Object.cshtml` if you don't like the default behavior and alter this behavior to better suit your needs.

Comment: for the ICollection<int> what do you suggest then. I don't see what are you suggesting

Comment: I suggest to use a view model containing 2 properties: one that will hold the selected values and another one to hlod the list of available values. And then strongly type your custom editor template to this view model instead of only `ICollection<int>`. Something like this maybe: `public class ListVm { public ICollection<int> SelectedValues { get; set; } public ICollection<int> Values { get; set; } }`. And then in your `CopyFromVM` class you will have `public ListVm EntityIds { get; set; }`. Now inside your editor template you will simply use the following ... (to be continued)

Comment: ...: `@model ListVm @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedValues, Model.Values.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() }))`.

Comment: Ok I see thanks for the suggestion it make sense for a view model but I don't really like it if that is not a veiw model class but a proper model. Suppose that your model using the MetadataSource pattern. Wouldn't it be better to use AdditionalMetadata attribute?

Comment: Sounds like with the `@Html.EditorFor()` I have to hanlde the label and stuff by myself.